# How do I fetch and Request Data from Figma API library using Google App Script

Tags: rest, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, fetch-api, figma-api

I am trying to route the text node to create text in Google App script. I basically have the code running through a loop take text from Figma and place it in google slides. I'm not sure why the API is not running. here is my code.

link to the Figma API: https://www.figma.com/developers/api

```
function fuctionn2() {
{
    var accessToken = "25582-30567a98-fd4a-4a86-a9a9-7a7b57f77d17"; // Please set your access token.
    var fileKey = "AKNad61GojhTj0TlTnn9AC"; // Please set the file key.

    var baseUrl = "https://api.figma.com/v1";
    var params = {
        method: "get",
        headers: {"X-Figma-Token": accessToken},
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
    };
    var fileInfo = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl + "/files/" + fileKey, params))
  var children = args = [
    "text = vector",
    "text=characters",
    "outputDir=./lib/build"
  ]
  }
    var response = request.postData.getDataAsString(.);

  // save that JSON to a file
  DriveApp.createFile('post.json', postJSON);
  *var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseURL {'text': true});*
Logger.log(response);
    if (RunText.err) {



        var s = SlidesApp.create("sampleSlide");
        var shape = s.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, 100, 200, 300, 60);
        var textRange = shape.getText();
        var selectionType = selection.getSelectionType();
        var keys = Object.keys(children.t);


        textRange.forEach(function(c, i) {
            textRange.setText(children.t[c]);
            textRange.insertText(chlidren.length);
            if (i != textRange.length - 1)s.insertSlide(i+1)
            });
    } else {
            throw new Error(children);
        }
    }
```

I tried running this JSON file through my function and my file was able to react the JSON Fille but now I need to get this JSON file in my script.

t is still seen as undefined

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `create the text at any instances that are created in Figma` and about your goal. Can you provide the detail information of it? If you can do, can you provide a sample input and output you expect as the images?

Comment: @Tanaike I am trying to export data from Figma to Google slides. When I said create the text at any instances that are created in Figma I meant `take text from Figma and place it in google slides`

Comment: Thank you for replying and additional information. All texts in the Figma file can be retrieved with Figma API. But unfortunately, I cannot still see the vision of your goal from your script and question. When there are several texts in a page and the Figma file has several pages, can I ask you about the goal you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike I just updated my script I figured out how to pull the JSON file from the API but now I need to run it in my code some how.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot understand about `var chlidren = args = ["text=vector","text=characters","outputDir=./lib/build"]`. Can I ask you about it? And I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still see your goal. When there are several texts in a page and the Figma file has several pages, can I ask you about the goal you expect?

Comment: I found how to do that on https://github.com/schalkneethling/figma-action/blob/master/entrypoint.js

Comment: the goal is to grab from the JSON file to populate the text in a google slides file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202295/discussion-between-zachary-blumstein-and-tanaike).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202297/discussion-between-zachary-blumstein-and-tanaike).